# How can I use Fuse on Dracut initramfs?

Tags: fedora, fuse, initrd

I want to use Fuse in initramfs.

I am using the Fedora OS, and the Fedora OS initramfs is Dracut.
I have created a sample application with Fuse to mount a folder with application.

I want to use Fuse on Dracut, but the Fuse application does not work in it. I get the error:

> libfuse.so.2 not found

How can I install Fuse to Dracut initramfs image?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should just copy your **libfuse.so.2** from **/lib** or wherever you have it to **/lib** on your initramfs?

Comment: It did not work. , i copied libfuse.so.2 to /lib , but still not works. 
I don't think it can be so easy

Comment: And what does `ldd yourappname` print?

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest solution is to compile your application statically.

Comment: I compiled application statically, all is ok in normal fedora system. But when i try to run same program in dracut, this error occures.

Comment: Very strange because **libfuse.so** is a shared library and static executables do not use shared libraries.